# Finding a given VTK module with CMake

Tags: cmake, vtk

I am currently trying to add a clipping plane to my dataset on vtk for android.
No problem on the code so far but I have issues building the .apk as my program will not compile.
In order to be able to use the clipping plane as I intend to I have the following includes:

```
#include <vtkTransformPolyDataFilter.h>
#include <vtkClipPolyData.h>
#include <vtkSampleFunction.h>
#include <vtkPlane.h>
#include <vtkImplicitPlaneWidget2.h>
#include <vtkImplicitPlaneRepresentation.h>
```

Yet when I try to compile (thanks to a Cmake generated Makefile) I get:

```
error: vtkImplicitPlaneWidget2.h: No such file or directory
 #include <vtkImplicitPlaneWidget2.h>
```

So I thought that I should try and add the vtkInteractionWidgets component to my find_package() in my `CMakeLists.txt` to obtain this:

```
find_package(VTK COMPONENTS
  vtkInteractionStyle
  vtkRenderingOpenGL2
  vtkRenderingVolumeOpenGL2
  vtkRenderingFreeType
)
```

Yet when I do so, I get:

```
Requested modules not available:
vtkInteractionWidgets
```

So I checked my modules list in my `vtkbin/lib/cmake/vtk-7.1/Modules` and I can clearly see: `vtkInteractionWidgets.cmake`

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance :).

---

EDIT:

I did check VTKConfig.cmake which has: `set(VTK_MODULES_DIR "/Users/.../VTK/vtkbin/lib/cmake/vtk-7.1/Modules")`. This directory as stated above does contain the `vtkInteractionWidgets.cmake`.

However I noticed that my `/Users/.../VTK/vtkbin/CMakeExternals/Install/vtk-android/lib` does not contain the equivalent lib. The only lib that I have containing the keyword interaction is: `libvtkInteractionStyle-7.1.a`

Comment: Have a look at CMakeFiles/CMakeErrors.log why a component was not found. If that does not help, read the FindVTK.cmake file and check what variables are set. This will help to identify the problem.

Comment: I cannot seem to find FindVTK.cmake

Comment: You are right. Quoting the CMake 3.1 release notes: "_The :module:`FindVTK` module has been removed altogether.
  It was a thin-wrapper around ``find_package(VTK ... NO_MODULE)``.
  This produces much clearer error messages when VTK is not found.

  The module also provided compatibility support for finding VTK 4.0.
  This capability has been dropped._"  So you have to check your VTK.config instead.

Comment: @usr1234567 Apparently my comment did not go through. Please see my edit for an updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns this has to be done manually in the `vtkAndroid.cmake` file in `VTK_SOURCE/CMake/vtkAndroid.cmake`. There should be inside some lines to manually add each needed modules:

```
# Now cross-compile VTK with the android toolchain
set(android_make_flags
  -DANDROID_NDK:PATH=${ANDROID_NDK}
  #...
  -DModule_vtkFiltersCore:BOOL=ON
  #...
```

In my case I needed to add: `-DModule_vtkInteractionWidgets:BOOL=ON`